# Inherited class is not shown

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 classes: first of them is inheritor of QWidget and the second one is inheritor of the first class. When i launch my program i get 2 windows of first class. Why? And another question. Second::Second(QWidget *pwgt): First(pwgt) - is this string correct? i.e. should i send pwgt to constructor of the first class?

firstclass.h

```
#ifndef FIRSTCLASS_H
#define FIRSTCLASS_H
#include <QtGui>

class First: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    QLabel *firstText;
    QPushButton *firstButton;

public:
    First(QWidget *pwgt = 0);
};

#endif // FIRSTCLASS_H
```

firstclass.cpp

```
#include "firstclass.h"

First::First(QWidget *pwgt)
{
    firstText = new QLabel("First Class Text");
    firstButton = new QPushButton("First Class Button");

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(firstText);
    lay->addWidget(firstButton);

    this->setLayout(lay);
}
```

secondclass.h

```
#ifndef SECONDCLASS_H
#define SECONDCLASS_H
#include <QtGui>
#include "firstclass.h"

class Second: public First
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QLabel *secondText;
    QPushButton *secondButton;

public:
    Second(QWidget *pwgt = 0);

public slots:
    void changeText();
};

#endif // SECONDCLASS_H
```

secondclass.cpp

```
#include "secondclass.h"

Second::Second(QWidget *pwgt): First(pwgt)
{
    secondText = new QLabel("Second Class Text");
    secondButton = new QPushButton("Second Class Button");

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(secondText);
    lay->addWidget(secondButton);

    connect(secondButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeText()));

    this->setLayout(lay);
}

void Second::changeText()
{
    firstText->setText("From second class");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "firstclass.h"
#include "secondclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    First first;
    Second second;

    first.show();
    second.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the layout with `setLayout(lay);` in the `First` class' constructor. This is correct, especially if you create objects of the `First` class. However when you create objects of the `Second` class, the `First` class constructor still called. In the following code:

```
First first;   // Calls the First class constructor
Second second; // Calls both First and Second class constructors
```

As Qt documentation states that

> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another.

This means that once you set the layout in the `First` class constructor, the attempt to set it again in the `Second` class ignored. As a result you see the first layout in both cases.

WRT your second question: yes, usually you have to pass the argument to the base class constructor. You even had to pass the parent to the `QWidget` class in your `First` class constructor:

```
First::First(QWidget *pwgt) : QWidget(pwgt) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for help a lot. Help me to solve this problem, please. How can i get one window of the first class and one window of the second class?

Comment: @IvanovIvan, Do not inherit class `First` in class `Second`. Make them separate, i.e. `class Second: public QWidget {};`.

Comment: Well, there is in my real program i use QTabWidget. In main class i have SqlDatabase and i need to get access to it from different tabs. I dont really know how to do it.

Comment: @IvanovIvan, store the pointer to your database in each of the tabs, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You call `setLayout` twice on your second widget - once in the First constructor and then again in the Second constructor. But the second one will be ignored: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setLayout

Why are you inheriting like this anyway, if they're supposed to look completely different.